# SQL Server target platform dacpacs won't publish to Microsoft Azure SQL v12

Tags: sql-server, azure, version, dacpac

I am recreating an Azure resource group deployment that contains a working azure `sql` server. I am repeating the targeting of a `dacpac` to an azure `sql` server instance that has exactly the same specs. I believe I am doing it the same way I did it a year ago.

My method uses a Visual Studio database project spun off ASP Net Core Web App Solution (web app database in VS SQL Server Object Explorer>Create New Project)

Create targeted dacpac

- right-click on project name in VS Solution Explorer & choose Properties
- under VS Project Settings* choose the target platform
- replace default Target Connection String in Properties>Debug
- navigate back to VS Solution Explorer. Right-click on VS Project again & choose Project Snapshot
- the following file type `rollbasesqldatabase_20230301_14-19-35.dacpac` is written to Snapshots folder in VS project
- navigate to connected Azure `sql` server instance in VS SQL Server Object Explorer
- right click and choose Publish Data-tier Application

The error I'm getting is familiar. But I'm getting it for all versions:
`Publish failed. An error occurred during deployment plan generation.` `Deployment cannot continue.` `A project which specifies SQL Server 2014 as the target platform cannot be published to Microsoft Azure SQL Database V12.`
This occurs for me on target platforms SQL Server 2012, 2016 & 2019 too

My data source server is:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=aspnet-rollbase-6D7D2449-EB25-45CE-A8D3-EDAB69CDCAB3;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

My publish database connection is on this server in VS:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV13;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

My Properties>Debug edit is from:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV13;Initial Catalog=rollbasesqldatabase;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Connect Timeout=30
```

Edited
`Data Source=rollbasesqlserver.database.windows.net;Initial` `Catalog=rollbasesqldatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User` `ID=rollbaseAdmin;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect` `Timeout=60;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False`

I noticed the `V13` reference  of the server which hosts the database that I (right-click) Publish Data-tier Application. Is this relevant? This post [Purpose of ProjectsV13 LocalDB instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211082/purpose-of-projectsv13-localdb-instance) seems inconclusive to me.

Other than this I have no idea why this `dacpac` deployment fails when I have done it before.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to deploy an ASP Net Core Entity Framework SQL Server Database to Azure. In order to run a Web App with an Azure SQL backend.

- GitHub Actions/Workflow `dacpac` with `YAML` file
- Visual Studio publish Data-tier Application using `dacpac`
- Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (same as above)
- As well as others like Azure Data Studio & the command line `sqlpackage` all using `dacpac` file

But I found another way that produced more helpful warning/error messages.
Assuming the Azure resources are present. And therefore there is a Azure SQL Server & Database.

- In MSSM connect to the Azure SQL Server Database
- Right click on the database name
- Choose Tasks
- Choose Upgrade Data-tier Application

So in this way I take it I was upgrading from blank Azure SQL Database template to one with a schema.

I still got errors. But these were specific so helpful.

[image: Detailed Error Message]

Here the first warning is the previous '`Publish failed. An error occurred` ... etc' But it's just a warning. And qualifies this by saying there may be 'compatibility issues'. The real error is that I made a dumb mistake by leaving an `sa user` hanging around after development. Deleting this user allowed the upgrade to go ahead successfully.

This shows how much variation there is with error messages. Prior to getting this information I had no idea why my database deployment was failing.