# Connecting to local SQL Server database from C# project

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

I am running Visual Studio 2017 with SQL Server Object Explorer. I have been unable to connect to a local SQL database, although I copied the connection string directly from the SQL Server properties window. I created a tiny test project just to work on making this connection work, but nothing I try is working. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

My Connection String:

> (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=SportsStore;Integrated
>   Security=True;Connect
>   Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False

Error I am receiving:

> Keyword not supported: '(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;initial catalog'. at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable
>   parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable
>   synonyms, Boolean firstKey) at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString,
>   Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String
>   connectionString) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String
>   connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions&
>   userConnectionOptions) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString,
>   SqlCredential credential) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString) at
>   TestWebApp_DotNetFramework.index.btnTestDBConn_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) in c:\users...

Comment: That's not a valid connection string.  You need something like `Server:`.

Comment: Thanks. I have corrected my connection string, and now I'm getting a 'better' error message - just need to go through other comments and see what *else* I'm doing wrong. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `Data Source` attribute too. Your connection string should be like this.

```
Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=SportsStore;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

Comment: Thanks, don't know how I missed that!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't copy/paste connection strings directly from MS SQL Server Studio. If you want to connect to LocalDB, then this post is going to help
[How to connect to LocalDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534454/how-to-connect-to-localdb)

Answer (score 0):

Your error code says:

> Keyword not supported: '(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;initial catalog'.

Which means that connection string parameter is mistype. if you want more information about connection string parameters, visit this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax)

try to add **"Data Source = "** in the begin of your string.

hope that help