# What is the name of MSSQLLocalDB 2016 in services list

Tags: sql-server, windows-services, connection-string, sql-server-2016

At last, I used sqlserver often at 2005s. now just installed VS2017. and it seems MSSQLLocalDB 2016 connection name of instance is changed from .\SQLEXPRESS to something like: (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB and it doesnt connects. and I checked the list services.msc and couldnt find any relevant name "sql".
is it removed in services ? or its not a service anymore maybe a standalone app ? (thanks)

and look! I dont ask why I cannot connect. Im asking the name of "SQL Server" in services.msc. is it now a standalone app ratherthan being a background server task?

it just doesnt exists anymore ? or am I missing something

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to LocalDb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534454/how-to-connect-to-localdb)

Comment: thanks but I dont ask why I cannot connect. Im asking the name of "SQL Server" in services.msc. it just doesnt exists anymore ? or am I missing something

Answer (score 1):

> it seems MSSQLLocalDB 2016 connection name of instance is changed from
>   .\SQLEXPRESS to something like: (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB

These are just two differnt products.

> LocalDB installation copies a minimal set of files necessary to start
>   the SQL Server Database Engine. Once **LocalDB** is installed, you can
>   initiate a connection using a special connection string. When
>   connecting, the necessary SQL Server infrastructure is automatically
>   created and started, enabling the application to use the database
>   without complex configuration tasks. Developer Tools can provide
>   developers with a SQL Server Database Engine that lets them write and
>   test Transact-SQL code **without having to manage a full server instance
>   of SQL Server**.

he cite is taken from here: [SQL Server 2016 Express LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb)

So SQL Server Express is a **full** server instance (and also win service) while Localdb is not.

Answer (score 0):

You cant find SQL Server in services.msc

if you wish to configure the SQL SERVER you can just search in your computer an application named : "*SQL SERVER 2016 Configuration Manager*" - then you can for example turn off\on the SQL Server and etc .

Answer (score 0):

(localdb)\MsSqlLocalDB does not run as a Windows/System Service, so you will not see it listed in Services.msc

As mentioned previously, MsSqlLocalDB is the 'developer edition' of SqlExpress and is normally run as an 'in-process' database server, not as a out-of-process service.

When your application runs, and it opens a connection to MsSqlLocalDB, the proces of Opening the DB connection will cause the MsSqlLocalDB engine to be instantiated within your current process, and then your application will be using it. When your application exits, MsSqlLocalDB will normally exit also.

You can run SqlExpress and MsSqlLocalDB at the same time. SqlExpress will normally be running as a Windows Service under the connection point '.\SqlExpress' and when your application runs it will instantiate '(localdb)\MsSqlLocalDB'