# SQL Server 2017 Express LocalDB available?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2017

Is localdb available for SQL Server 2017? I.e. `(localdb)\ProjectsV14`.

In Visual Studio Professional 2017 (15.5.3) under '.NET desktop development tools' I only see 'SQL Server 2016 Express LocalDB'.

I need this to code locally against SQL Server 2017 functions, targeting Azure production environment.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55994 **Details -> LocalDB (SqlLocalDB)**

Comment: At this moment is not available. Lookin gwhole day and seems it is not available on July 2018

Comment: The url seems legit to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local SQL Server Express DB can be obtained from
[Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Express Download](http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55994)

Note that the server\instance name has changed:

- `(localdb)\ProjectsV13` (SQL Server 2016)
- `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` (SQL Server 2017)

Comment: The default LocalDB instance for SQL Server 2016 for devs to use is [`MSSQLLocalDB`, not `ProjectsV13`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27201328/145173).

Comment: Edward Brey, did it change name or is it a different service?

Comment: They are separate LocalDB instances with [separate purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23658871/145173). MSSQLLocalDB is for applications; ProjectsV*x* is for SSTD.