# Database shows up in Visual Studio but not SSMS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I'm running the sample code I downloaded from GitHub for the project here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x

So, in Visual Studio, I can see the aspnet-IdentityDemo DB created in the object explorer, but when I go to SSMS and refresh things, I don't see it. How come it isn't showing up in SSMS?

Comment: Did you connect to the Server and then checked if the database was present?

Comment: most likely using localdb version which is not going to be found in ssms. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534454/how-to-connect-to-localdb

Comment: Thanks I’ll give it a try when I get home!