# When I try to connect to the instance of MS SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB the error "Can not create auto instance" has place

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection

There is an instance of MS SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB installed on my computer. But when I try to connect to it via SQL Sever Management Studio 2016 I have the error "Can not create auto instance". I use the following server name when I try to connect: "(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB". I discover that name using the following command line command: "C:>SQLLocalDB i". This command returned me the following result "MSSQLLocalDB". But if I use to connect (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB string then the abovementioned error occurs. When I try to connect to this server programmatically (in my application) using the following connection string:

```
"Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Trusted_Connection=yes"
```

and use providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" then "Can not create auto instance" error also has place. Why I cant connect to MS SQL Server 2014 Express LocalDB. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the backslash (with an additional backslash) or preceding the entire connection string with `@` to disable escaping? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463228/unable-to-connect-to-localdb-in-vs2012-a-network-related-or-instance-specific/12463683#12463683

Comment: It hasn't helped unfortunately.